# Weird formulas to represent recursive sets

Tags: first-order-logic

(I'm self-studying from Kunen's book *Set Theory:  An Introduction to Independence Proofs* after nearly 30 years out of the field as a practicing lawyer.)

Problem $23$ asks us to assume $\operatorname{Con}(\text{ZF})$ and prove there is a first order formula $\psi$ that represents "$x$ is even" (if $x \in \omega$ is even, ZF proves $\psi([x])$ and if $x \in \omega$ is odd, ZF proves $\lnot \psi([x])$ but such that ZF does not prove $\forall x \in \omega ~(\psi([x]) \lor \psi([x+1]))$.

I'm at a loss.  I wondered whether it was some sentence that's not true of non-standard numbers but then I realized that can't be right because there's no first-order way to distinguish standard numbers from non-standard numbers.  Nor can I figure out some way to incorporate some statement that's independent of ZFC.  This isn't a starred exercise so it's not supposed to be difficult, but for the life of me I'm out of ideas.  What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the problem if you remove the even/odd thing and just ask for $\psi$ such that ZF proves $\psi(x)$ for each $x\in\omega$ but ZF does not prove $\forall x\in\omega: \psi(x)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey It seems like pretty much the same problem, but I can't think of how I'd approach that one either (other than the approaches I've already rejected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Nor can I figure out some way to incorporate some statement that's independent of ZF.

Well, that's at least in the right direction: namely, you're definitely going to want to combine the usual definition of even-ness with some ZFC-undecidability.

Throughout I'll be horribly informal, but hopefully clear. Let's assume - correctly - that our definition is going to have the form $$\varphi(x):\quad x\mbox{ is even } \wedge \psi(x)$$ for some "bonus condition" $\psi$. The idea is that we want $\psi([n])$ to be ZF-provable for each specific $n$, but the sentence $\forall x(\psi(x))$ to not be ZF-provable.

Our most basic source of undecidability is of course consistency, and we're going to make headway by unpacking it. Specifically, the *single* sentence Con(ZF) really has the form "$\forall x(\theta(x))$," where $\theta(x)$ is intuitively "$x$ is not a (code for a) proof of $\perp$ in ZF." When we think about this, we notice that this is looks a lot like our desired $\psi$ - the key point being that *each specific code* can be checked in ZF.

So we're led to consider the formula

> $x$ is even and is not a (code for a) proof of $\perp$ in ZF.

Do you see why this works?

Comment: So the answer to @EricWofsey's comment above is simply $\theta(x)$ (using your notation).  I'll think on this some more but I think I see it.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, when we drop evenness we're just looking at what I've called $\theta$.